# Why is $\frac{d}{dx} F^n(x) = n \cdot F^{n-1}(x) \cdot \frac{d}{dx} F(x)$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

question is in the title. I know the chain rule is used ($f(x) = g(h(x)))$, but i don´t know what is picked as $g(x)$ and $h(x)$.

Comment: $g(x)=x^n$, $h(x)=F(x)$

Comment: The notation $F^n(x)$ is confusing. Could be confused with applying $F$ $n$ times - i.e. functional composition.

Comment: Would you use $F(x)^n$?

Comment: Yes, or even $[F(x])^n$. And if $y = F(x) = cos(x)$, and $n = 3$, then what is the derivative of $[cos(x)]^3$? Answer: Use the product rule as if $x$ was inside the brackets, but then multiply by the derivative of what is inside the brackets (an 'adjustment').